# How do i return multiple values in Option type in Scala?

Tags: scala, tuples

```
def solve(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double): Option[(Double, Double)]= {
val disc = b*b - 4 * a * c;
val root1 = (-b + disc) / 2*a);
val root2 = (-b - disc) / 2*a);
}
```

I understand that (root1, root2) will create a tuple, and I want to return the tuple in Option type. I wonder how to do it in scala?

Comment: What are you trying to return when `a` is 0?

Comment: @Brian obviously infinitum :)

Comment: @Brian I would guess `None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers cover parts of what I'm guessing you're trying to do, but not the whole of it, which I think is: implement the quadratic formula returning either a pair of roots or `None` if there is no solution. Given that, your current implementation is also calculating the formula incorrectly. For reference, the formula is:

```
x1 = (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a
x2 = (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a
```

The correct implementation:

```
def solve(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double): Option[(Double, Double)] = {
  val sqrtDiscriminant = Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)
  val twiceA = a * 2

  if (a == 0) None
  else
    Some(
      ((-b + sqrtDiscriminant) / twiceA,
      (-b - sqrtDiscriminant) / twiceA))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple really.

```
Some((root1,root2))
```

[Check out this article and the rest of the series](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html)

Comment: I was stuck because I tried to implement the none as well. For example if I am tryting to solve(1,0,1) it should return a none.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment from the answer provided by @WillD, it seems that you want to return `None` when an exception occurs (presumably in calculating either `root1` or `root2`?) In this case, you could surround each calculation with [scala.util.Try](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Try.html), and convert each result to an `Option`:

```
import scala.util.Try

def solve(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double): Option[(Double, Double)] = {
  val disc = b*b - 4 * a * c
  val root1: Option[Double] = Try((-b + disc) / (2*a)).toOption
  val root2: Option[Double] = Try((-b - disc) / (2*a)).toOption

  // If both `root1` and `root2` are calculated successfully, return the tupled values.
  for {
    r1 <- root1
    r2 <- root2
  } yield {
    (r1, r2)
  }
}
```

When we call this method with values `0`, `1`, and `0`, we notice something strange happens:

```
scala> solve(0,1,0)
res0: Option[(Double, Double)] = Some((NaN,-Infinity))
```

I'm not entirely sure why, but I believe it has to do with the imprecision of `Double`. Hopefully someone else can chime in with a better answer as to why this returns `NaN` and `-Infinity`. However, if we replace all occurrences of `Double` with `BigDecimal`, we get much better precision, as well as the desired output:

```
import scala.util.Try

def solve(a: BigDecimal, b: BigDecimal, c: BigDecimal): Option[(BigDecimal, BigDecimal)] = {
  val disc = b*b - 4 * a * c
  val root1: Option[BigDecimal] = Try((-b + disc) / (2*a)).toOption
  val root2: Option[BigDecimal] = Try((-b - disc) / (2*a)).toOption

  // If both `root1` and `root2` are calculated successfully, return the tupled values.
  for {
    r1 <- root1
    r2 <- root2
  } yield {
    (r1, r2)
  }
}

scala> solve(0,1,0)
res1: Option[(BigDecimal, BigDecimal)] = None
```